# Как сделать чтобы float элементы не переносились но новую строчку?

Tags: html, css, html5, float

При ширине браузера меньше `800px`. http://codepen.io/sharov/pen/XbqRqd

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
   <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>

.main {
 min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 1000px;
  }

  .left {
 width: 200px;
 background-color: grey;
 float: left;
   }

   .right {
     width: 600px;
     background-color: lightgrey;
     float: right
}
```

Пробовал делать элементы `inline` и ставить им `white-space: nowrap`. Не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Может, достаточно будет увеличить `min-width` для `div` с классом `main`?

```
.main {
    min-width: 820px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ширину родительского блока сделайте равной 800

Answer (score -1):

```
.right {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: right
}
```